# One or more things that made fingerprint unique?

Tags: cordova, tracking, fingerprinting

I have on app who was write in cordova.
I want to make fingerprint with users data to track installs.
At click, we make a hash. If this hash it is equal with hash from install.. it is ok and count + 1 at install.
I tried with ip...lat..lng..., but ip is changing from mobile network and hash from click is not equal with hash from install.
I also tried with client js (but user agent is different because I use in cordova InAppBrowser plugin who uses WebView).
And resolution sometimes is different.. depend of which browser it was used I think.

What can I use to make fingerprint unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you think about Wifi MAC address + info about devices present in this class (ID, brand, version, ...):
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build